# Foursquare API: Venues visited by a user sort

Tags: foursquare

For the Foursquare api

[Venues visited by a user](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/venuehistory)
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/venuehistory

I was wondering if we can change the sort of the venues coming back?  It appears to be sorted by alpha.  It would be helpful to sort by most recent checkin.  Or in addition to the beenHere field add a last_checkin_id: or just date would be fine.

Is there a sort query string parameter that i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The venuehistory endpoint simply returns all the venues that a user has been to. If you're looking to sort venues by most recent check-in, consider using the [user/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins) endpoint instead.

Comment: user/checkins, would work, it would be a lot more processing for foursquare and us.  If I checkin to a place everyday, i will page through all results to get the same info in the venuehistory.  Just a suggestion since I saw that this call was experimental.